# Contradictory boundary conditions in electrostatics problem?

Tags: electrostatics, boundary-conditions

Consider the following problem: A conducting cube of side $a$ is grounded. Inside there's a horizontal (i.e., perependicular to the $z$ axis) sheet with uniform surface charge density $\sigma$. The objective is to find the electrostatic potential $\phi$ inside of the cube, using Laplace's equation $\nabla^2 \phi = 0$.

I'm not going to ask about the math since that's not the problem. My issue is that I have a conceptual problem with the boundary conditions. First, the potential should be zero at the faces of the cube (where $x$, $y$, $z$ are each $0$ or $a$). Second, there should be a jump discontinuity in the $z$ component of the electric field $E_z = - \partial_z \phi$ proportional to $\sigma$. Now suppose we stand on the charged sheet, very close to the edge of the cube. Since the sides are equipotential surfaces, the electric field will be perpendicular to them. This means that $E_z$ will be zero on both sides of the sheet, which contradicts the fact that there should be a jump of $\sigma$.

Does my reasoning make sense? I can back it up with math if needed; the general idea is that we can write $\phi = \sum_{n,m} \sin(\frac{n\pi}{a}x) \sin(\frac{m\pi}{a}y) f(z)$, but there's no way to write $\sigma$ as a sum of sines, since any such sum will necessarily be zero at $x,y = 0, a$.

*Edit:* The previous paragraph is wrong (nonuniform convergence of series!), but the physical side of question still stands.

Comment: Does the charged sheet touch the conducting cube? Or is it insulated from it?